# Errors with Google Glass bar code projects

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-glass, barcode

I am trying to create a bar code scanner app for google glass that is similar to ones already out there like Zbar, BarcodeEye, or ZXing. However when I download the projects from github and import them into my eclipse workspace they become riddled with errors. Some examples from the ZXing project. https://github.com/zxing/zxing

for ZXing, inside the BenchmarkActivity.java file
benchmarkTask.execute(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR); *execute is errored out

in BenchmarkAsyncTask.java
MultiFormatReader reader = new MultiFormatReader(); *MultiFormatReader is not recognized

It seems like the errors are usually eclipse not recognizing the types and methods declared by the developer, which lead me to think I may not have the right SDK's installed. This seems strange to me though, because I have the Glass sneak peek installed. And yes I have tried importing.

Comment: zxing uses Maven as build system and to define its dependencies. You need an plugin to make Eclipse understand Maven, see http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html